# Linux dump(8) outputs nothing

Tags: linux, linux-mint, backup, dump

I am dumping my live partition. 
All works ok in terminal. Until the 100%.
I dump from live mint partition to an USB key.

```
$ dump -0f /dev/sdc1 /dev/sda2
```

Once done, I look at my USB key.
Nothing on it, full free space according to disk tools.

Am I wrong somewhere ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you give,

```
dump -0f /dev/sdc1 /dev/sda2
```

will back up the contents of `/dev/sda2`, overwriting all the first partition of your USB key (which won't mean much to standard disk tools then).

If you want to generate a backup file on your USB key instead, you need to mount the key and tell `dump` to dump to a file on the key:

```
dump -0f /media/usb/backup /dev/sda2
```

will create a file named `backup` on the key (you need to replace `/media/usb` in the command with the real mountpoint for the key).

You can specify a mountpoint instead of a device to back up:

```
dump -0f /media/usb/backup /
```

will back up the root filesystem.

Comment: `dump(8)` can read from devices just fine.  From the manual: _`files-to-dump` is either a mountpoint of a filesystem or a list of files and  directories  to  be  backed up as a subset of a filesystem._ But yes, it makes more sense to write the image to a file, rather than a raw device.

Comment: @lcd047 Yes, as I mentioned; but from the manual: *In the former case, either the path to a mounted filesystem or the  device  of an  unmounted  filesystem  can  be  used.* (The "former case" is specifying a mountpoint.)

Comment: Thanks @Stephen Kitt, I'm trying to do it, but no "usb" in media... ? Do you know why ?

Comment: It's just an example, you need to give the mountpoint used for your USB key.

Comment: @StephenKitt That's confusing phrasing in the manual, the "unmounted filesystem" is not limitative, it still works if you read from a device while mounted.

Comment: @lcd047 Ah right, OK, I hadn't tried using a live filesystem like that...

Comment: Thanks @Stephen Kitt. Just done : "dump -0f /media/usb/backup /", and I get "cannot output ...real path.... : is a directory". In spite of : I can copy file into this dir path. Do you know why ? I m using live filesystem.

Comment: Is `/media/usb/backup` a directory by any chance?

Comment: @StephenKitt. nope. media folder has 2 subs: oem & myuser. usb drive folder is in myuser (media/myuser/7r634854-b..../). When I provide this path, issue... but when I browse it, i see my folders in it : i have created a backup one e.g. I see it... but when provided to dump, issue. :/ Oh oh, I m  retrying just now... seems ok. I have simply deleted the folder "backup". Dump needs a filename, not a folder... your answer is just right.

Comment: What path are you providing? Just `/media/myuser/7r634854-b..../`? You need to give the name of a non-existent **file** to use, not a target directory.

Comment: I ve done it. That s ok. Thank you @StephenKitt